# PHPStorm Yosemite xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I just set up a new Yosemite machine with Homebrew (no MAMP), with virtual hosts. And I'm having a helluva time getting the debugging to work.
I have followed the instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html to no avail.
There are no errors, but the breakpoints are ignored.

Very frustrating.

Does anyone have any insight on how to get this to work? Or is anyone willing to help me walk through my setup?

Comment: So .. what you have got there? Show your xdebug config/prove that you have it installed? If it installed -- what xdebug log says?

Comment: Show your configs. Also some detail about your php/apache install is useful (version, config, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong PHP executable in PHPStorm.
Thanks for helping!